# Erlydtl: is there a way to render list of records in template?

Tags: templates, erlang

For example I have:

```
-record(usr,{name,email}).
...
Usr1 = #usr{name="John", email="john@host.com"},
Usr2 = #usr{name="Jane", email="jane@host.com"},
Usr3 = #usr{name="Alex", email="alex@host.com"},
{ok, Result} = template_dtl:render([{users, [Usr1, Usr2, Usr3]}]),
...
```

and I want to use it like:

```
{% block content %}
{% for user in users %}
<a href="mailto:{{user.email}}">Send mail to {{user.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Anybody have faced with same problem?

Comment: My approach has always been to convert the record to a proplist: lists:zip(record_info(fields, record), tl(tuple_to_list(MyRecord)))

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells, could you show usage example in template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Records are syntactic sugar on top of tuples**. `Usr1`, `Usr2` and `Usr3` just are tuples, and precisely:

```
Usr1 = {usr, "John", "john@host.com"},
Usr2 = {usr, "Jane", "jane@host.com"},
Usr3 = {usr, "Alex", "alex@host.com"}.
```

The template does not know how to interpret these records, as it doesn't know the record definition at compile time.

There are three solutions to your problem. In all cases, the template will be the same and you should write `user.email` and `user.name` as you did.

### Teach erlydtl about your records

`record_info` compile option is precisely meant to tell erlydtl about the records used in template variables.

```
erlydtl:compile_template(Template, TemplateModuleName, [{record_info, [{usr, record_info(fields, usr)}]).
```

The drawback is that you might not call `erlydtl:compile*` yourself and therefore adding `record_info` option can prove difficult. Besides, the piece of code that calls this function must know the record definition which you will probably have to move to an `.hrl` file.

### Transform your records to a dict:dict(), a proplist() or a gb_trees:tree()

This is what [Soup d'Campbells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384685/soup-dcampbells) suggests in their comment. You can also use compile-time function `record_info/2` for this purpose. The easiest indeed is the `proplist()` form:

```
lists:zip(record_info(fields, usr), tl(tuple_to_list(Usr1))).
```

`tuple_to_list(Usr1)` evaluates to `[usr, "John", "john@host.com"]`, while `record_info(fields, usr)` is equal to `[name, email]`.

### Encapsulate data in modules

Records are not really good to capture data structures with public accessors (`user.name`) because they are better maintained locally to a given module, as this makes code updates much easier. Alternatively, you could define a module (called `usr` or `app_user` but not `user` as such a module already exists) that would export `name/1` and `email/1` accessors.

Erlydtl magic here is based on the feature previously known as parametrized modules, and more precisely the ability to call a function using a tuple, instead of an atom, as a module name. You do not really need a parametrized module, just pass a tuple matching an existing module.

For example, your `app_user` module could look like this:

```
-module(app_user).
-export([new/2, name/1, email/1]).
-record(?MODULE, {name :: string(), email :: string()}). % private to this module.
-type app_user() :: #?MODULE{}.

-spec new(string(), string()) -> app_user().
new(Name, Email) -> #?MODULE{name = Name, email = Email}.

-spec name(app_user()) -> string().
name(#?MODULE{name = Name}) -> Name.

-spec email(app_user()) -> string().
email(#?MODULE{email = Email}) -> Email.
```

(`?MODULE` is used instead of `app_user` because this only works if the record's name matches the name of the module, and this code will work even if you rename the module).

Then, in your code, instead of:

```
Usr1 = #usr{name = "John", email = "john@host.com"}
```

You would write:

```
Usr1 = app_user:new("John", "john@host.com").
```

Usr1 is just a record, or more precisely the tuple:

```
{app_user, "John", "john@host.com"}.
```

Erlydtl will nevertheless be able to process `Usr1` directly. It will consider it a parametrized module, as `app_user` exists as a module (it's the module above). Therefore, during template rendering, it will call `app_user:name/1` and `app_user:email/1` accessor functions, passing them the whole record.

Comment: So difficult as for newbie... Thanks!

Comment: According third way, how i can evoke, for example `app_user:name/1`, in my template? When I call `{{app_user:name(item)}}` in template body, I get error.

Comment: According second way, how to extract property from property list in template body?

Comment: All three solutions work with the template you posted. Just pass records (solution 1), proplists (solution 2) or parametrized modules (solution 3) and Erlydtl will do the right thing. In the third case, app_user:name/1 is invoked at template rendering and you could actually include some logic.